# Getting json data from football site with python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests, scraper

I am trying to scrape the website in this link:

https://www.whoscored.com/Players/11119/Show/Lionel-Messi

I want to get the data from the Summary, Defensive, Offensive tabs and i tried
this:

```
import requests
# This is the json data link i wish to get from the defensive tab (from developer tools)
url = "https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics?category=summary&subcategory=defensive&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=true&playerId=11119&teamIds=&matchId=&stageId=&tournamentOptions=&sortBy=Rating&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=Overall&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=false&page=&includeZeroValues=true&numberOfPlayersToPick="

response = requests.get(url)

print(response.json())
```

I can't manage to print the json data and scrape the data I need from the tab, am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The URL, at least as written in this question, is not valid.

Comment: The response is HTML, not JSON, so that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

When executing your code as provided, the response comes back with a 403 "Forbidden" status.

Probably this provider doesn't want their data scraped and checks the request for signs of non-browser access, and returns this error.

Be sure to check your `response.status_code` before proceeding.

Comment: The status is indeed 403, is there anyway I can still scrap the data?

Comment: Have you tried adding a header with basic stuff like user-agent?

Comment: @jlaur I did try adding a header with user-agent, I am pretty new to the requests library and do not understand what those extra parameters do, I've only been using requests.get(url), didn't add any parameters to it.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/. Basicalle you instantiate the session class like so: session = requests.Session(). You then first query the sites real url (the first link in your post). Like so: response = session.get(your_url, headers=your_header). This should store a cookie in requests. You should then query the link that gives you the 403. real_response = session.get(json_url, headers=your_header).